# 'ImageDataGenerator' object has no attribute 'flow_from_dataframe'

Tags: python, python-3.x, machine-learning, computer-vision

I am trying to build an image classifier for the Cancer Detection Kaggle Challenge. This is the code that I am using.

```
`train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255,
                                   validation_split=0.15
)

test_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)

train_path = MAIN_DIR + '/CancerTrain'
valid_path = MAIN_DIR + '/CancerTrain'



train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
                dataframe = train_labels,
                directory=train_path,
                x_col = 'id',
                y_col = 'label',
                has_ext=False,
                subset='training',
                target_size=(96, 96),
                batch_size=64,
                class_mode='binary'
                )

validation_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
                dataframe=df,
                directory=valid_path,
                x_col = 'id',
                y_col = 'label',
                has_ext=False,
                subset='validation', # This is the trick to properly separate train and validation dataset
                target_size=(96, 96),
                batch_size=64,
                shuffle=False,
                class_mode='binary'
                )`
```

However, whenever I run it I get this error:

```
`AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-22-eb9c70d0ad1c> in <module>()
     15                                                    )
     16 
---> 17 train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(
     18                 dataframe = train_labels,
     19                 directory=train_path,

AttributeError: 'ImageDataGenerator' object has no attribute 'flow_from_dataframe'`
```

I have looked everywhere and can't seem to find a solution. Is the method called something different now?

Comment: What version of `keras-preprocessing` do you have installed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to make use of the `flow_from_dataframe()` method I suggest you do the following:

Uninstall the current keras-preprocessing module:

```
pip uninstall keras-preprocessing
```

Install the keras-preprocessing module from the following git link:

```
pip install git+https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing.git
```

(you can see the method is available [in the source code here](https://github.com/keras-team/keras-preprocessing/blob/master/keras_preprocessing/image/image_data_generator.py))

and then import the `ImageDataGenerator` as follows:

```
from keras_preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator
```

Comment: hey, this is not working for me, what can I do?

Comment: I'd suggest you post a new question with the details of your issue

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error using Keras 2.1.4. I simply upgraded with `pip install keras --upgrade`.  Keras 2.2.4 does not give the same error.  It all works now.

Answer (score 0):

This also gave me an error with Keras 2.2.2 and keras-preprocessing 1.0.2. With that configuration, after uninstalling keras-preprocessing (pip uninstall keras-preprocessing) and reinstalling it (updating to 1.1.2) it will give:

```
ERROR: keras 2.2.2 has requirement keras_preprocessing==1.0.2, but you'll have keras-preprocessing 1.1.2 which is incompatible.
```

It successfully installed version 1.1.2 and the "object has no attribute" error no longer appeared when using flow_from_dataframe.